# Compression in PutTCP - ListenTCPRecord Communication in NiFi

Tags: json, tcp, apache-nifi, compression

I have a particular use case where I am transferring a batch of JSON messages between two **NiFi** Clusters using **PutTCP** & **ListenTCPRecord**.

Is there a way to apply compression to the messages being sent out via **PutTCP** and to decompress the message at the **ListenTCPRecord** end ?

Comment: the [CompressContent processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CompressContent/index.html) could do compress/decompress...

Comment: Yes. But, I couldn't make it work properly with PutTCP & ListenTCPRecord.

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't compression/decompression built into the TCP processors, but I think it would be a reasonable request.

You could use CompressContent before PutTCP, but then I don't think you can use ListenTCPRecord on the receiving side since its going to be reading compressed data looking for records and won't find them, so possibly using regular ListenTCP and then sending the results to CompressContent in decompress mode, and then to whatever record processors you need. I haven't tried that though so not totally sure if it works.

Comment: I did try using ListenTCP. But, its not working properly with multi-line data. Hope there is a work-around for this.

Comment: Ok then I think it would be an enhancement to have all of the network related processors support compression and decompression, I created this JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5564